# How to index an epoch nanoseconds value as a date or date_nano in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

Our system stores its values in Epoch nanoseconds timestamps, i.e. `"created_at": 1629469976984334600`, which are imported as such in an Elasticsearch index.

When the field is mapped on a new index, I get unexpected results:

- mapped as `"type": "date_nanos"` → the original integer numbers (?)
- mapped as `"type": "date"` → dates in year 51,213,565-ish, e.g. `+51213565-09-01T05:06:38.320Z`

Is there some mapping syntax that tells ES to treat the nanoseconds number as a proper date, even if the result is milliseconds or seconds precision?

Comment: I think this could be achieved with a transform but I never used those. Maybe it's time to dive into it.

Comment: Can you show with an example what you'd like to achieve? You'd like `1629469976984334600` to be transformed in your source document to a normal date at ingest time? If yes, is it because you'd like dates to be returned from your search queries instead of long numbers?

Comment: Moreover, it's unlikely that `1629469976984334600` is a valid date_nanos value: I'm getting the following error when trying to index it: `date[+51637818-01-03T02:18:54.600Z] is after 2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807 and cannot be stored in nanosecond resolution`

Comment: Hi @Val  That nanoseconds value is what is ingested in ES in the index I use as source. The value seems correct, it's _"Aug 20 2021 14:32:56 GMT+0000"_ I double checked here https://www.unixtimestamp.com

Comment: Can you also answer my earlier comments?

Comment: To clarify, yes, I have numerical values for `created_at` in the initial index, and would like to map/transform them to date values in a new index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too much digging, a failed bounty and more digging, I found a way.

In a `_reindex`, you can use a `script` to manipulate the data, like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "mydocs"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "mydocs_mapped"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.created_at = (long)ctx._source.created_at / 1000000;"
  }
}
```

This converts the field to epoch milliseconds and Elasticsearch and Kibana can use it as a date.

I almost teared up.

PS: Official documentation is here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docs-reindex.html#reindex-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to simply add the nanoseconds precision to the mapping itself, something like this -

```
PUT new_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "new_date_field": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer to elastic's [built-in date formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats)

Comment: I did try, no luck.

Comment: did you try `strict_date_optional_time_nanos` as the `type`?

Comment: I just did, and got the error _"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason" : "No handler for type [strict_date_optional_time_nanos] declared on field [transaction_at]"_ My system is on "amazon-opensearch" and limited to ES 7.10, could this cause it?

Comment: I am sorry. `type` should be `date` and `format` should be `strict_date_optional_time_nanos`

Comment: 7.10 is basically the same in terms of built-in date formats - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: Getting a field of type `date` with simple numerical values, e.g.  
1665429707060598800
  Here's how it appears in Kibana https://drive.google.com/file/d/11hHxRLhhF9E_h1um9gWeeIPG7fVVuFRd/view?usp=sharing